# Click() in Selenium java looks like has "clicked" but nothing happens. In IE browser

Tags: java, selenium, internet-explorer

I am trying to open a new "lookup window" which is the output of the click on a "search button".
I am trying to automate this using Selenium in java.

The code that I have tried is:

```
scrollToElement(webDriver, elementInput);
jsExecuter.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", elementInput);
```

and,

```
scrollToElement(webDriver, elementInput);
elementInput.click();
```

I am validating the "click" using try catch, and no exception is thrown which is why I am assuming it clicks. But the lookup window doesn't show.

The HTML for elementInput is:

```
<td class="comp-button" onclick="javascript:return getDefaultValue('8','ReaderOneId','ReaderOneName',false,'Reader1');">
                    <a onmouseover="$('#Reader1Img').attr('src','/Content/images/btn_lookup_hover.png');" onmouseout="$('#Reader1Img').attr('src','/Content/images/btn_lookup.png');" href="javascript:void(0);">
                        <input name="Reader1Img" class="image-lookup" id="Reader1Img" style="border: 0px currentColor; border-image: none;" type="image" alt="" src="/Content/images/btn_lookup.png">
                    </a>
                </td>
<a onmouseover="$('#Reader1Img').attr('src','/Content/images/btn_lookup_hover.png');" onmouseout="$('#Reader1Img').attr('src','/Content/images/btn_lookup.png');" href="javascript:void(0);">
                        <input name="Reader1Img" class="image-lookup" id="Reader1Img" style="border: 0px currentColor; border-image: none;" type="image" alt="" src="/Content/images/btn_lookup.png">
                    </a>
<input name="Reader1Img" class="image-lookup" id="Reader1Img" style="border: 0px currentColor; border-image: none;" type="image" alt="" src="/Content/images/btn_lookup.png">
```

I am accessing this image button using,

`By.id("Reader1Img")` which is the value passed to `elementInput`

And am finding the element using the same then trying to click on it.

When I try to "findElement" a value is returned which is not null, hence it is able to find the button.

I can also see the color of the "Search_icon" or the image turn blue, but the lookup won't open.

Comment: Could you post your code that you use to find `elementInput`, and also the HTML for `elementInput`? This will help us track own if it's an issue with your selector or webelement. If `.click()` and Javascript click are both not working, it could be an issue with selector clicking something you do not expect.

Comment: What's the element you've selected? Are you sure that's the element that has the click action on it?

Comment: Element that you have selected should have click event so just make sure that

Comment: Have you ever tried to use F12 developer tools to check whether it contains some error? Try to add debugger in the button click event and check whether the click event is executed?can you post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding capability `nativeEvents` as false to enable click in Internet explorer browser.

```
DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer(); 
caps.setCapability("nativeEvents",false);
WebDriver driver = new  InternetExplorerDriver(caps);
```

Comment: I tried setting the capability but it's not working for me. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @Christine elementInput is just a By.id() String. The HTML for it is, <input name="Reader1Img" class="image-lookup" id="Reader1Img" style="border: 0px currentColor; border-image: none;" type="image" alt="" src="~/Content/images/btn_lookup.png">

Comment: Can you please post your full here?

Comment: i have edited the question. Please find the html for the image button I am trying to click in it now.

Comment: Can you also post your time DesiredCapabilities?

Comment: these are the cap set for IE ````DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();   cap.setCapability(IEDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS, true);    cap.setCapability(IEDriver.ENABLE_ELEMENT_CACHE_CLEANUP, true);
cap.setCapability(IEDriver.NATIVE_EVENTS, true);    cap.setCapability(IEDriver.IE_ENSURE_CLEAN_SESSION, true);    cap.setCapability(IEDriver.IGNORE_ZOOM_SETTING, true);   cap.setCapability(IEDriver.UNEXPECTED_ALERT_BEHAVIOR, false);    cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.UNEXPECTED_ALERT_BEHAVIOUR, UnexpectedAlertBehaviour.IGNORE);````